# How to make a hyperlink in telegram without using bots?

Tags: hyperlink, telegram

How to make a Hyperlink in telegram?
how to make a hyperlink in telegram without the help of bots?

Comment: Use [@Bold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602062/5033247) to send message to urself and tap it to  copy.

Answer (score 156):

As of Telegram Desktop Version 3.1.1, You can format the your message like:

Create link:

```
Ctrl + K = this pops Create link field and auto fills selected text on Text
```

Other useful hotkeys:

```
Ctrl + B = Bold
Ctrl + I = Italic
Ctrl + U = Underline
Ctrl + Shift + S = Strikethrough
Ctrl + Shift + M = Monospace
Ctrl + Shift + N = Plain Text
Ctrl + Shift + X = Strikethrough
```

Comment: How about the mobile version, please? Isn't there any way to do this without a bot on the mobile version of Telegram? And if not, what's the best bot for that please?

Comment: @Franky, there is. you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644077/3515141)

Comment: Strikethrough is "Ctrl + Shift + X"

Comment: Does not work on Telegram Desktop version `9.6.3.245683 AppStore`.

Comment: For macOs Telegram Desktop, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53265448/3263250 worked for me

Answer (score 64):

On Telegram Desktop for macOS, the shortcuts differ. You can right-click a highlighted text, then hover over `Transformations` to see the available options:

[image: macOS Telegram Desktop Formatting Shortcuts]

Comment: Is it possible to modify shortcuts ?

Answer (score 27):

On **Telegram Desktop**, use this hot key:
`Ctrl+K`

On **iOS/iPadOS**:

1. Select the text.
2. Tap on `Format`.
3. Tap on `Link`.
4. Paste the link.

On **Android**:

1. Type your text.
2. Select it.
3. Click on `Create Link` from its options.

You can see these steps in this image:

[image: link creation in telegram android]

Answer (score 21):

You can make a hyperlink in Telegram by writing an URL and send the message.
Using [Telegram Bot APIs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) you can send a clickable URL in two ways:

**Markdown**:

```
[This is an example](https://example.com)
```

**HTML**:

```
<a href="https://example.com">This is an example</a>
```

In both cases you will have:

> [This is an example](https://example.com)

EDIT: In new version of Telegram clients you can do that, see above answers.

Comment: In question he wrote  "without bots", So i think it's impossible  without bots

Comment: @N1gthm4r3 yes, it's impossible. But you can use the inline bot `@bold` with the Markdown syntax.

Comment: But in the header you still see **via @bold**, it's not clean

Comment: OK, how to add that bot to our groups? I looked at the page, but it's only talking about features. I didn't find a way to add that Telegram bot to groups to be able to use its features in there. :(

Comment: This doesn't actually work if the URL has special chars in it such as _ in odd numbers.  telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 715  calling bot.sendMessage(chat_id=id, text=msg, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')

Comment: 2021 now you can create links without bots .See my answer

Answer (score 11):

**Step 1:**Select the text you want to give to the hyperlink.

[image]

**Step 2:**Select the three dots at the above right corner.

[image]

**Step 3:** click `create link` from the options

[image]

**Step 4:**   insert the url

[image]

Select `ok` then the link will be created

Comment: This is excellent. It works in all telegram's current versions.

Answer (score 6):

In the new desktop versions, you can add hyperlink by pressing ctrl + k and typing links.

Answer (score 4):

My phone is **xiaomi Redmi note 8** with **MIUI 11.0.9** . There is no option for create hyperlink :[image]
So I use **[Telegram desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/)** or **[Telegram X](https://telegram.org/blog/telegram-x)** for create hyperlink because **Telegram X** supports *markdown*. Type url and send message (in *Telegram X*) or there is an alternate way which is the easiest!

## Update

##### This way works for all phones!

Select the text using Word Editor and click in the three dots on the top right corner of the chat. It is usually used for accessing settings but if you select a text and click there, you can see Telegram's own Formatter!

Comment: As of now (2020-10-08), this solution (and Markdown) also works on plain Telegram for Android (not only Telegram X). Thanks, it's very useful for MIUI users!

Comment: Yeah. New Updates are great!

Answer (score 2):

Try this link format:
https://t.me/[YourUserName]

I was looking for such a thing, BUT with text in (like the one that WhatsApp got)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iOS and (still, after all these years) don't have the button to create a link you can use [this shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/2a5f904a2ce5498986ad83d925632812) to create a link with custom text.

URL is taken via "share" action, clipboard if the shortcut wasn't called via "share" menu or requested from user.

The result is put in the clipboard, you just have to paste it into telegram.

Answer (score -2):

First make link with @bold bot . Then Copy text and paste it to remove "via @bold"