# How do you add a hyperlink to a message in telegram on mobile?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'd like to do something along the lines of "Hey, checkout this link" and have it formatted with a hyperlink on desktop and mobile. I'm not looking to make my own bot if possible but I'm happy to use others. I've found the @bold bot can format a hyperlink if it is the only thing in the message but I would ideally like to have other text as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a hyperlink in telegram without bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299085/how-to-make-a-hyperlink-in-telegram-without-bot)