# How to send link of photo in telegrambot api without showing link?

Tags: telegram

i want to send link of photo in SendTextMessageAsync method in TelegramBot but this method show the link of photo.

Comment: If you just want the photo, not the link, you should first download the photo from the link and then upload it to telegram.

Comment: i want to send text message with more that 200 characters and photo in single text message

Comment: If you upload the photo, 200-character limit can't be lifted. If you link the photo, you can't remove the link from message. Therefore, what you want to do is not possible so far.

Comment: i uploaded photo to server and add link of it to text message, in telegram photo and its link Shown to users!

Comment: You must use the parse_mode and then send the hyperlink!

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69642261/6013016)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upload your image and use the URL.
For sending hyperlink with the bot API you can simply send HTML markup and use `parse_mode`. See [telegram documents](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style):

> To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field when using sendMessage. The following tags are currently supported:

```
<a href="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg">&#160</a>
```

`&#160;` is the hidden character.