# Attach a file to a long text in Telegram Bot API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to attach a file into a long text in Telegram Bot (Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583130/send-an-image-link-to-telegram-without-display-image-url/46780833) question for an image). So, Thanks to web preview feature of Telegram, I know that using HTML/Markdown markup, I can do so.

But I actually want to attach a file inside Telegram chat (and I have file_id and I could find also the file path). So, I was thinking that getting the file URL by *getFile* method and then using the *https://api.telegram.org/file/BOT_TOKEN/FILE_PATH* as the URL of the link may work but that doesn't happen! Plus, even if this works, using this would probably reveal my bot token [because they can access to the link if the link text is hidden].

Apart from downloading the file in a server [which is very costly when the file size is very big], what is the solution?

Or maybe I should not use this *mark up* feature and there is another way that I should follow?

I know that there most probably **is** a solution because there are already couples of "telegram attach bot".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't just pass `file_id` for that at this time :(

But here has a simple solution, you can create a **public** channel with **username**, and forward/upload all file to that channel, then link to there. For instance:

```
@Sean_Bot md Here is [simple](https://t.me/tdfiles/4) file
```